# How to call a custom post type with WP_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

How do I call a custom post type with `WP_Query`?

This is my custom post type. How do I display it in my code?

```
<?php
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
function setup_types() {
    register_post_type('mytype', array(
        'label' => __('My type'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
        'show_ui' => true,
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'setup_types');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'mytype' );                                              
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

More information You can find here: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type'        => 'your custom post type here',
'posts_per_page'   => 5,
'category'         => '',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post(); 

} // end while
} // end if
wp_reset_query();
```